# Eclipse auto shutdowns when creating new project

Tags: kubuntu, java, eclipse

When I click finish on a new project in Eclipse which I installed with this command ***sudo apt-get install eclipse-platform***. This popup window comes and no matter if I choose Yes or No it closes the application:

[image]

I have tried running eclipse from terminal so I can see what happends, but I'm not so good to find out the problem, but this is what I get:

```
jeggy@jeggy-Dell-System-XPS-L502X:~$ eclipse
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 14: reading configurations from ~/.fonts.conf is deprecated.
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f305f07a528, pid=11475, tid=139846321936128
#
# JRE version: 7.0_25-b30
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libgobject-2.0.so.0+0x19528]  g_object_get_qdata+0x18
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/jeggy/hs_err_pid11475.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-7/
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

That font error is because I'm running Kubuntu, and I get that error right away but I don't think it has anything to do with it closes when I create a new project. And if anyone is interested I posted the [pid11475.log here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6646024/). And as it says there ***try "ulimit -c unlimited"***, I have tried that but didn't change anything.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue as well on Kubuntu 14.10. I wasn't even able to change the theme under System Preferences -> Application Appearance because eclipse crashed as soon as I tried to click "Application Appearance".

But editing the gtkrc file under /usr/share/themes/oxygen-gtk/gtk-2.0/ as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26436009/eclipse-luna-crashes-on-new-project-in-ubuntu finally did the trick.
Change this line:

```
 GtkComboBox::appears-as-list = 1
```

to:

```
 GtkComboBox::appears-as-list = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it turned out to be due to oxygen-gtk theme. After choosing a different gtk theme (QtCurve neither work), I've seen no more crashes. On KDE, you can change these settings on System Preferences -> Application Appearance -> GTK .
Changing GTK2 theme is enough.