# Eclipse luna crashes on new project in Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, eclipse, crash

I'm having some trouble getting **Eclipse Luna** to work. I downloaded the tar.gz from their site and I downloaded the tar.gz for the **Java JDK**. I extracted everything and Eclipse opens properly, but when I try to make a new project, it crashes on me. In the terminal I ran `java -version` and it tells me I have version **1.8.0_25** so I don't think I have an issue with java. Now, this happens if I try to make any kind of project. Eclipse opens the wizard for creating a new project of a particular type and then the whole application crashes. I'm using **Kubuntu 14.04**. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a stacktrace from the crash? Can you show us the output of get when you start eclipse from the terminal?

Comment: there is a generated file when eclipse is crashed in the same directory of eclipse go to figure out what is tells you. Or past it's contents.

Comment: When I run it in the terminal, Eclipse does give me a ClassCastException, but it still opens. When I try to create a new project, I get this: `java: /build/buildd/gtk2-engines-oxygen-1.4.5/src/animations/oxygencomboboxdata.cpp:87: void Oxygen::ComboBoxData::setButton(GtkWidget*): Assertion '!_button._widget' failed.
`.

Comment: On KDE oxygen is the default theme, but I do not have oxygen applied right now.

Comment: Just found related content, worked fine for me, except look and feel is not what I like now.. Hope that helped. http://askubuntu.com/questions/396410/eclipse-auto-shutdowns-when-creating-new-project?rq=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As indicated in [Eclipse auto shutdowns when creating new project](https://askubuntu.com/q/396410/44876) one workaround to this [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=440660) is to change the GTK2 theme in System Preferences -> Application Appearance -> GTK (I personally use [Aurora](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/GTK_Engines): `sudo apt-get install -y gtk2-engines-aurora`).

Alternatively, a patch to oxygen is available [here](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=339174), and has been pushed to the active development branch of oxygen. [oxygen-gtk2-1.4.6-1](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/gnome/gtk2-engines-oxygen) should be OK but as of now oxygen-gtk2-1.4.5 is still the most recent stable version.

Comment: or run eclipse as `GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/themes/Raleigh/gtk-2.0/gtkrc eclipse`